# Absolute value and limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, absolute-value

Could you give me, please, some counterexamples to the following statement:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |X_n|= |a| \Rightarrow  \lim_{n \to \infty}  X_n = a $$

I know, that 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = a \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}|X_n|= |a|$$
because $|.|$ is a continuous function. However, despite I know, that the converse should be false, I can not construct any explicit counterexamples. Please, help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $X_n=(-1)^n$

Comment: What have you tried?  It is important that there are two values of $a$ that have the same value of $|a|$

Comment: OP should think about under what conditions on $x_n$ the implication does hold.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_n) = (-1)^n$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |x_n| = 1$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n $ does not exist.

Comment: Yes - but a non-existent limit is something different than a limit not equal to something. And IMVHO the latter seems closer to what OP was meaning.

Comment: @CiaPan OP asked for a counter-example and the above sequence is one. But I couldn't think of an example like what you're describing, so if you have one in mind please post the soln! :)

Comment: I was about to post it, but Patrick Cook was faster :) The modulus function yields the same result for opposite values of argument: $|c|=|-c|$ so it's enough to take a constant, non-zero sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}=c\ne 0$ and change its sign: $\lim x_i \ne -c$ even though $\lim |x_i|=|-c|.$

Answer (score 1):

A trivial counterexample follows:

$X_n = -a~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then clearly $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n|=|-a|=|a|$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n=-a\neq|a|$

A nontrival counterexample follows:

$X_n = (-1)^n~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $|X_n|=1~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1 = 1$. But $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n$ does not exist (it merely "oscillates" between 1 and -1).